# visual studio 2015 update 2 RTM and RC debugging context not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, roslyn

**Update 1:**

After Updating visual studio to version 2015 update 2 RTM the problem still exist.

**Update 2 patch available 4/12/2016** :

Thanks to Patrick Nelson.

a patch has been released

You can download the patch [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt695655.aspx).

**Update 3 8/16/2016:**

Latest vs 2015 update 3 [KB3165756](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx) has the same problem do not update

**Version Used:**

Latest stable version on visual studio update 2 rc

Disabled all my extensions and also restarted my all settings

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Install visual studio update 2 rc
2. Create new project using asp.net mvc core template
3. Debug the app

**Expected Behavior:**

To be able to debug the asp.net application
 [image]

**Actual Behaviour:**

I can't explore context of variable inside visual studio editor or immediate windows i get the following error in immediate windows

[image]
error CS0103: The name 'myvariable' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Log a bug on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: i already added an issue on github but seems stackoverflow be faster

Comment: If it reproduce in watch window\immediate window and data tip than it problem in the expression evaluator or in some other concord component [look here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Concord-Architecture). I don't think Roslyn has a relation to it.

Comment: @DudiKeleti any workaound?

Comment: @1AmirJalali use your own concord components ;) but seriously, I don't have any magic workaround, sorry.

Comment: Same issue here, if anyone find a work around it would be great

Comment: are you sure the assembly is build in debug mode, w/o optimizations? Make sure web.config contains `<compilation debug="true">`

Comment: Im using debug.writeline ahhhhhhh

Comment: @m0sa yes absolutely

Comment: Are you running against coreclr? I think I read somewhere that various debugging features are missing running against coreclr; switch to full clr if you haven't already? (i.e. `dnvm list` should show a full clr variant in use with the `deafult` alias).

Comment: @Smudge202 I tested both no success

Comment: How did you switch between them and did you re-open the solution after switching? I'm currently installing the full Update 2 (upgrade from RC) so can't confirm, but I'm almost certain I can get debug support when on full clr. You can see which dnx is in use in the output window.

Comment: @Smudge202 using dnvm use from property page and so on.... the second picture in question shows debugging on coreclr before update 2

Comment: `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r clr -p` ? Then re-open solution for changes to take effect, ensuring this setting is *not* overriden in the project properties?

Comment: @Smudge202 i have done that

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry for the runabout; I'll test in update 2 shortly and let you know if it at least works on the non-rc update.

Comment: I was having this problem with an existing code base and the solution in [Visual Studio 2015 Debugging: Can't expand local variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730100/visual-studio-2015-debugging-cant-expand-local-variables) worked for me.

Comment: Why do you not update to Update 2 Release version?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a bug that was introduced in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.  Essentially the debugger is unable to inspect local variables in dynamic modules.  We released a hotfix for it today.

You can download the patch [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=785969).  Documentation for the patch is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt695655.aspx).  Let me know if the patch does not fix your particular scenario.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. Flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: What if the question is not the same, but the answer is?

Comment: Then tailor your answer to the specifics of the question.

Comment: Why is this patch not being pushed out via the built in VS notification flag? Come on MSFT....

Comment: This bug was bugging me. Simply stop making bugs :)

Answer (score 20):

using trial and error method i found a workaround for know that will bring back context debugging.

```
from tools >  options > debugging > general then enable
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

and also (Use Managed Compatibility Mode - Enabled) please make sure json configuration file has this sections

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }, 
    "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. I add to add the "dnx451" reference as well in order for debuggin to work. Why is this? In my test solution I just want to compile for the dot net core.

Comment: FYI, I have a project that only targets `dnx451` that exhibits this bug. I don't think that adding `dnx451` will always resolve this. The patch, on the other hand, fixed it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for visual studio 2015 update 3, 14.0.25420.01
I just removed "debugType": "portable" from project.json
Now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio Update 3 I reset my Visual C# settings and it worked.