# Locals missing during debugging in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, xunit

**Issue**
Locals only displays `this` variable while debugging, other local variables are not available in *Locals* or *Watch* but can be re-evaluated in *Intermediate Window* in Visual Studio

[image: Visual Studio Debugging Window with Missing Locals]

**Brief**
I'm debugging an Xunit test for some code I am writing. The library I am testing targets ASP.NET Core RC1. Here is my `project.json`:

`{
  "authors": [ "Matthew Abbott" ],
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
  "description": "Provides tests for the Fx.Content.Composer package",
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-rc1-build3168",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204",
    "Fx.Content.Composer": ""
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "projectUrl": "",
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}`

When debugging the unit test (I'm using Visual Studio's in built test features), I can set breakpoints, but the Locals/Watch windows don't allow me to inspect local variable declarations. I also do not get variable tooltips for those local variables.

If I copy and paste my statements into Intermediate, they are then added to scope, but I can't debug easily straight off the bat.

**Things I've tried**

- Ensured I am compiling in Debug mode
- Disabling JIT optimizations
- Reset my Visual Studio settings

**Things of note**

- I've recently installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 2
- I've restarted the IDE several times without success
- I've restarted my machine serveral times without success
- Not explicitly bound to a unit test debugging session - when I F5 to run, they fail there also

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
Based on Victor's comment, I tried stepping through into a method from that unit test, and initially a parameter is available in scope, but a variable defined further down is not.

[image: Partial missing locals?]

Comment: I've seen this before. In my case, it was only the first method in which the breakpoint was hit that was missing the locals. If I would step in another method, locals would show up. If that's the case, then you might have to reinstall VS - that's what worked for me

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci I tried stepping through to a method, and initially my parameters are available in **Locals**, but if I step through, a local declaration is not available. I've attached an updated screenshot

Comment: Running on debug or release?

Comment: As detailed above - I'm always checking I'm in Debug mode. Just re-installing VS and seeing if that fixes it...

Comment: Re-install didn't fix the issue :-/

Comment: It is a known bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730100/visual-studio-2015-debugging-cant-expand-local-variables.

Comment: Thanks! That actually seemed to fix it - I had stumbled across that OS question previously, but as the question author was using 2015 Preview, and we're now on 2015 Update 2, I would have hoped this would have been solved - I'll progress through a Connect bug and see if its actively being fixed

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** Note this answer only applies to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.  If you are missing locals in any other release of Visual Studio, something else is going on.  **You can only install the hotfix patch over Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.** Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and later already have the fix.

**Original Answer:**

This looks like a bug that was introduced in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.  Essentially the debugger is unable to inspect local variables in dynamic modules.  We released a hotfix for it today.  You can download the patch [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=785969).  Documentation for the patch is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt695655.aspx).  Let me know if the patch does not fix your particular scenario.

Thanks!

-Patrick Nelson

Comment: I had OP's issue since Update 2 but could not even see variables in the immediate window (while it seems he could). This patch fixed the issue for me!

Comment: @Chris I could only get the variables in Intermediate if I redeclared them there, they wouldn't evaluate if I didn't. Installed the patch but haven't tested yet

Comment: I have the same issue in VS 2015 Update 3 and can't install that Update 2 patch for it.

Comment: Yes me too I have update 3 and can not install this fix. It is really annoying