# VS 2015 Locals window disappear

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, I am suddenly unable to see my locals window.
It was working fine a couple of days ago, but since yesterday, if I click on Debug -> Windows -> Locals nothing happens. No window no nothing. Same thing if I click on Debut -> Windows -> Watch 1

Anyone else experiencing that? Is it a known bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locals missing during debugging in Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455772/locals-missing-during-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: I don't think so, in this one the person at least sees a window...I don't get anything

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with Windows -> Reset Window Layout

Comment: This worked for me when my locals window disappeared while debugging Visual Studio 2019 Preview.

Answer (score 17):

While Debugging:

**Debug** > **Windows** > **Locals**

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What happened with my VS was #1. I had several windows open in VS. Window #1 had Locals Toolbar pinned to it Window #2 Did not. When I Toggled it off in Window #2 it appeared back in Window #1.

Reset works to