# Script inside a loop. error during 2nd execution

Tags: variables, ssis, script-task

I have an ssis package that runs a script task inside a loop.

```c
public void Main()
{
    int intCount;
    intCount = (int)Dts.Variables["User::Count"].Value;
    //some logic              
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

During the first iteration code works fine. during subsequent execution I get the below error if I try lookup the value of any variable in immediate window or quick watch

> Dts.Variables["User::Count"].Value error CS1704: An assembly with the
>   same simple name 'ST_850053c10abd463da6fd571ece4d8f95' has already
>   been imported. Try removing one of the references (e.g.
>   'ST_850053c10abd463da6fd571ece4d8f95.dll') or sign them to enable
>   side-by-side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["An assembly with the same simple name has already been imported" error without duplicate reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160634/an-assembly-with-the-same-simple-name-has-already-been-imported-error-without)

Comment: I'm afraid not. This is within a SSIS package. I haven't added any external reference. The assembly name referred in the error message is the default assembly of the script task.